# Invoke Operator & Operator Overloading in Kotlin

Tags: operator-overloading, kotlin

I get to know about the Invoke operator that,

`a()` is equivalent to `a.invoke()`

Is there anything more regarding Invoke operator than please explain. Also, I did not get any example of Invoke operator overloading.

Is Invoke operator overloading possible? If possible then can anyone please explain about the Invoke operator overloading with an example? I did not get anything regarding this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Yes, you can overload `invoke`. Here's an example:

```
class Greeter(val greeting: String) {
    operator fun invoke(target: String) = println("$greeting $target!")
}

val hello = Greeter("Hello")
hello("world")  // Prints "Hello world!"
```

In addition to what @holi-java said, overriding `invoke` is useful for any class where there is a clear action, optionally taking parameters. It's also great as an extension function to Java library classes with such a method.

For example, say you have the following Java class

```
public class ThingParser {
    public Thing parse(File file) {
        // Parse the file
    }
}
```

You can then define an extension on ThingParser from Kotlin like so:

```
operator fun ThingParser.invoke(file: File) = parse(file)
```

And use it like so

```
val parser = ThingParser()
val file = File("path/to/file")
val thing = parser(file)  // Calls ThingParser.invoke extension function
```

Comment: Can you please explain the second example more elaborately.

Comment: Sure, if you can tell me what about it you would like elaborated. Is there any part in particular that doesn't make sense?

Comment: Just explain the second program more elaborately.

Comment: I cleaned it up to show only the important bits. `ThingParser` just parses a file and converts its contents to a `Thing`. What that is or how it works is irrelevant, just that it has a function `parse(File)` that is a clear main action of the class.

Comment: Parser.invoke(file: File) or ThingParser.invoke(file: File)

Comment: Good catch, it should be `ThingParser` :) Fixed

Comment: It's awesome. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I reverted part of your edit as the point was to show that you can override `invoke` with extension functions on existing classes, which is great for working with existing libraries.

Comment: `invoke()` operator is not an extension function in Kotlin.  It is a higher-order function.

Comment: `invoke` is just an operator function. You can implement it as an extension function, a higher order function, neither, or both. In this case, it's an extension function and not a higher order function.

Answer (score 17):

**Operator Function invoke()**
Kotlin provides an interesting function called **invoke**, which is an **operator** function. Specifying an invoke operator on a class allows it to be called on *any instances of the class without a method name.*

Let’s see this in action:

```
class Greeter(val greeting: String) {
    operator fun invoke(name: String) {
        println("$greeting $name")
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val greeter = Greeter(greeting = "Welcome")
    greeter(name = "Kotlin")
    //this calls the invoke function which takes String as a parameter
}
```

A few things to note about **invoke()** here. **It**:

- Is an operator function.
- Can take parameters.
- Can be overloaded.
- Is being called on the instance of a Greeter class without method name.

Answer (score 10):

The most way to use a [invoke](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#invoke) operator is use it as a [Factory Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), for example:

```
//          v--- call the invoke(String) operator 
val data1 = Data("1")

//            v--- call the invoke() operator 
val default = Data()

//          v-- call the constructor
val data2 = Data(2)
```

This is because the [companion object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects) is a special object in Kotlin. Indeed, the code `Data("1")` above is translated to the code as below:

```
val factory:Data.Companion = Data

//                       v-- the invoke operator is used here
val data1:Data = factory.invoke("1")
```

---

```
class Data(val value: Int) {

    companion object {
        const val DEFAULT =-1
        //           v--- factory method
        operator fun invoke(value: String): Data = Data(value.toInt())

        //           v--- overloading invoke operator
        operator fun invoke(): Data = Data(DEFAULT)
    }
}
```

Comment: @AvijitKarmakar Not at all. it's my pleasure, :)

Comment: why not use named default value for parameter?

Comment: @Antek hey, this is only an example to introduce factory method. if you make the `Data` to interface you'll know why?

Comment: @holi-java hmm, not really - you can use default values for interfaces as well. Can you explain further?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers:

It's possible to define a class extending an anonymous function.

```
class SpecialFunction : () -> Unit {}
```

In such case, the operator `invoke` is already defined, so it needs to be overriden:

```
class MyFunction : () -> Unit {
    override fun invoke() { println("Hi Mom") }
}
```

One more thing about syntax repercussions:

If such "functor" is called right after constructing it, you end up with double parentheses:

```
MyFunction()()
```

And, if such functor returns another functor, you may see some obscurities like

```
MyFunction()()()()()...
```

perhaps including parameters. This will not surprise anyone coming from the JavaScript world, though.

Comment: Hey. so is it possible for this function to return something? i need to know more about this as it seems so powerful

Answer (score 2):

If you have some Python background,

you can think `invoke` in Kotlin as `__call__` in Python.

By using this, **you can "call" your object** as if it's a function.

One difference is: you can overload `invoke`, but there is no official way to overload methods in Python.