# What are different between supplier.invoke() and supplier() in a lambda in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

There are two funs, what are different between  supplier.invoke() and  supplier() ?

```
fun String.myAdd2(supplier: () -> String) = this + supplier()

fun String.myAdd3(supplier: () -> String) = this + supplier.invoke()
```

Comment: They are just the same if you didn't overload the `invoke`, see docs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45173677/invoke-operator-operator-overloading-in-kotlin).

Comment: @HongDuan AFAIK, they are exactly the same